# Message box without any buttons at all

Tags: java, swing, loops, timer, joptionpane

I want to create auto-disposing message dialog. Everything works beside that there is still an ok button to click.

I want to get read the button.

Please check out this code -> works perfectly:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CloseOptionPane {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        int timerDelay = 1000;
        new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
            int timeLeft = 3;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(timeLeft > 0) {
                    label.setText("Human player. It is your move!");
                    timeLeft--;
                } else {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(label);
                    win.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }) {
            {
                setInitialDelay(0);
            }
        }.start();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: JOptionPane doesn't support optionless panes, you'll need to make the frame yourself.

Comment: @zneak: no, don't make a "frame", make a JDialog.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is there any one-liner creating such an empty Dialog and inserting in it this label?

Comment: @yoda, `Is there any one-liner creating such an empty Dialog`, No, its about 4 lines of code. 1) create the dialog, 2) add the label, 3) size the dialog 4) make the dialog visible.